# app.css is not rebuilt when app.less changes using ember-cli-less

Tags: ember.js, less, ember-cli

I am using ember-cli for a new project and cannot get app.css rebuilt automatically when my app.less changes.

My environment includes:

`node: v0.10.32
 npm: 2.1.5
 bower: 1.3.12
 ember-cli: 0.1.2
 ember-cli-less: 1.0.4`

Brocfile.js includes:

`var app = new EmberApp({
  lessOptions: {
    inputFile: 'godeeptest.less',
    outputFile: 'godeeptest.css'
  }
});`

I have a `godeeptest.less` file in my styles directory.

Whenever I change `godeeptest.less`, the output file `godeeptest.css` is not built automatically. BUT, when I restart the ember server on my terminal, the output file is built and the browser window updates with the new styles, as expected.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to work as expected, where expected behavior is "change file, browser reloads"

thanks,

`Mark`

update #1

head of `godeeptest.less`:

`@import "bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";  // include bootstrap
.navbar-inverse {
  .navbar-textalt {
    color: green;
    .navbar-text;
  }
}`

Comment: Are all your files less files ?

Comment: Yes. my main .less file imports bootstrap.less and then adds some of my custom css. I updated the question with the beginning of the godeeptest.less file.

Comment: Are there any .css files there? Like app.css?

Comment: I m asking this since ember-cli needs all the files in the directory /styles to be of the same type

Comment: i currently only have 2 files in the styles directory (other than hidden `.gitkeep` file), both of which are .less files.

Comment: [jump in the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63494/ember-js) for a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I fixed the problem, which is not a problem with ember-cli or ember-cli-less. it's a problem with Dropbox. or more specifically, don't store ember-cli projects in a Dropbox folder if you want ember-cli to work properly.

I moved my project out of the Dropbox folder into another folder on my Mac, and the problem went away. so there is some conflict between the watcher and Dropbox, SPECIFICALLY with less files, but no other file types. (weird).

don't despair, "It could be that the purpose of your life is only to serve as a warning to others."